# Alterar atributo dentro de um array de objs (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Estou com o seguinte problema, dado o seguinte array de objs, eu gostaria de retornar o mesmo array, mas com idade *2

```js
const usuarios = [
  { nome: "Diego", idade: 23, senha: 123 },
  { nome: "Gabriel", idade: 15, senha : 123 },
  { nome: "Lucas", idade: 30, senha : 123 }
];
```

Outra dúvida, eu consigo por exemplo, alterar a senha de determinado usuario?
como se fosse no mysql que vc usa um where?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _" idade *2"_? o que queres dizer com isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue filtrar usuário utilizando a função [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) no primeiro exemplo se quer alterar apenas um elemento.
Ou você pode utilizar as funções [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) e [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para fazer a alteração em mais de elemento como no segundo exemplo:

```js
let usuarios = [
  { nome: "Diego", idade: 23, senha: 123 },
  { nome: "Gabriel", idade: 15, senha : 123 },
  { nome: "Lucas", idade: 30, senha : 123 }
];

// O find retorna o primeiro elemento que satifaz a condição
let usuarioAlterar = usuarios.find(function (usuario){ return usuario.nome =='Diego'});

console.log(usuarioAlterar);
usuarioAlterar.idade *= 2;
console.log(usuarios);



// exemplo 2
usuarios = [
  { nome: "Diego", idade: 23, senha: 123 },
  { nome: "Gabriel", idade: 15, senha : 123 },
  { nome: "Lucas", idade: 30, senha : 123 }
];

let usuariosAlterar = usuarios.filter(function (usuario){ return usuario.idade  < 30 ;});
console.log('usuariosAlterar', usuariosAlterar);

usuariosAlterar.map(function(usuario){usuario.idade *= 2; });
console.log('usuariosAlterar', usuariosAlterar);
```

Comment: Muito obrigadooo <3

Comment: Por nada, se solucionou, por favor marque como solucionado.